# NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces Method () doesn't match all the results from "ipconfig /all"

Tags: c#, wpf

So the problem is that the method returns different results from the ones you get from using the command "ipconfig /all" in cmd. Some adapters are returned the right way, but some are not, and information is missing or its different.  For example, some of the description lines in ipconfig match the ones in my wpf program, but some don't or are empty. All i pretty much want it to do is return a proper DNS suffix, description/name and the physical address itself.

**Main Window**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void detectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<MacAddress> macAddresses = GetMacAddresses();


        for (int i = 1; i < macAddresses.Count; i++)
        {
            Label label = (Label)this.FindName("label" + i.ToString());

            label.Content = "Connection Specific DNS suffix: " + macAddresses[i].connectionSpecificDnsSuffix + Environment.NewLine
        + "Description: " + macAddresses[i].description + Environment.NewLine +
         "Physical Address: " + macAddresses[i].physicalAddress;
        }

        int count = 0;
        foreach (var item in macAddresses)
        {
            count += 1;
        }


    }

    internal List<MacAddress> GetMacAddresses()
    {
        NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        List<MacAddress> macAdresses = new List<MacAddress>();
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
            MacAddress address = new MacAddress();
            address.connectionSpecificDnsSuffix = properties.DnsSuffix;
            address.description = adapter.Name;
            address.physicalAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            macAdresses.Add(address);
        }
        return macAdresses;
    }
```

**Class for storing data**

```
class MacAddress
{
    public string connectionSpecificDnsSuffix;
    public string description;
    public string physicalAddress;
}
```

**Edit:**
**cmd results**
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r44H.jpg)

**Returned results**
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ9Sf.jpg)

Comment: A lot of stuff is registered as "kind off a network adapter" without actually being one. The entirety of Bluetooth comes to mind. As do Virtual Network Adapters instaleld as part of any VM Solution. Just getting actuall usefull information out of Network Avalibility Check is kind of hard work: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64975/Detect-Internet-Network-Availability
So you need to be a lot more specific wich values you expected, and wich values you got. And if any of those are actually physical Network adapters to begin with.

Comment: I edited the OP and added the pictures

Comment: `for (int i = 1` uhh I think you're missing an address per adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not catching the right address. I'd suggest looping throught each MacAddress with a foreach loop and adding them to UI dynamically.

Infact, I tried and it works. Your method of looping is just wrong.